# What happens with AWS Aurora Read Replica in case of AZ failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, disaster-recovery, read-replication

I can't seem to find anywhere the answer to this question.

We have an AWS Aurora cluster with a R/W instance and a read replica (multi-AZ).
What happens with the read replica in case of a failure of it's AZ?

What would the DR plan be?

Will AWS create a new read-replica in a new AZ (because we have configured it as multi-AZ)? Do we need to create a second read-replica in another AZ just to factor in for this kind of failure?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I found the answer to this question.

The Aurora Auto scaling with Aurora replicas feature set to minimum 1 replica would fix this problem. This will ensure that a read-only replica will be provisioned in a different AZ in case when an AZ is offline.

Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: Can you link to any AWS documentation or blog post that supports this?